# Axure output for Django templates

Tags: python, html, css, django, templates

I'm quite new to web programming and start to play with Django. I used  default tutorial, and some other examples and everything was ok. However, right now I face the following problem: I created a prototype in Axure and wanted to integrate it with my existing project. Using Axure I generated html/css files and in Django created a "home" app. The problem is that when I put Axure's output in template/home folder, it's able to load the default home.html, but misses images and css files.

My home app structure is like this:

-home

--templates

---home

----data

----files

----images

----plugins

----resources

----home.html

```
<div id="u0" class="ax_h1">
    <img id="u0_img" class="img " src=""/>
    <img id="u0_img" class="img " src="resources/images/transparent.gif"/>
    <!-- Unnamed () -->
    <div id="u1" class="text">
      <p><span>Some text </span></p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

it's able to resolve this path inside Pycharm(doesn't give any error). If I go to the folder itself and run home.html everything is fine. But if I run the whole project and o to the home page, it seems like it cannot find the path to the file.. Shows icons, but without actual images.

Could someone help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up your static files [properly](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/).

Make sure `django.contrib.staticfiles` is in your `INSTALLED_APPS`

Add `STATIC_URL = '/static/'` (or whatever you want the static url to be) to your `settings.py`

Place static files in a folder called `static` in your app

```
home/
    templates/
        home/
            home.html
    static/
        images/
            transparent.gif
        css/
        js/
        ...
```

Then, you can use

```
<div id="u0" class="ax_h1">
    <img id="u0_img" class="img " src=""/>
    <img id="u0_img" class="img " src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/transparent.gif"/>
    <!-- Unnamed () -->
    <div id="u1" class="text">
      <p><span>Some text </span></p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I do have django.contrib.staticfiles in my INSTALLED_APPS, and STATIC_URL = '/static/' set in settings.py.
1) I tried your solution, by putting {{ STATIC_URL }} to several links  but it didn't work(I copied all the files, of course). However, adding "static/" like src="static/images/transparent.gif" works. I don't understand why {{ STATIC_URL}} doesn't, as I don't want to hardcode all the links. Any clue?

Comment: 2) Is there any way to create let's say another HOME_URL = '/templates/home/' to point to the files with {{HOME_URL}}? I tried this, but no result. The thing is that I already have a lot of html/css/js files created and I didn't want to go through all of them, to change the paths. 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I also use this
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
)